# How do you "Republish now" from a Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple Google Apps script that makes some changes to a row when you select a menu item, like adding a date to a certain column and changing the background colour (basically a "Mark as complete" action). I have "Automatically republish when changes are made" set as I publish the script to the web for consumption by a script, however this can take up to 5 minutes to update. Is there anyway to call a republish from my script that also makes the changes, so I can have it republish on that action? That's the only time I would want the script to publish changes anyway.